# How to typeset times in regular text

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, amsmath

How should I enter in a time of day in latex in order to have it typeset properly, if I am using the amsmath package? I am using pdflatex.

say I want to write "12:00". In math mode, this gives a space after the colon, as below:

```
%MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Should it be $4\colon 00$, $5:00$, or 6$\colon$00? They all have a space.

\end{document}
```

[image: withamsmath]

Without the package, it looks fine:

```
%MWE
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Without the amsmath package, 6$\colon$00 looks correct.

\end{document}
```

[image: withamsmath]

Comment: why not simply 5:00?

Comment: A time is not math, why write it in math mode?

Comment: I should have specified, I wanted all of the numbers in the document to appear the same. Since some of the numbers appear in math mode, I was typesetting all numbers in the text in math mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Simple**
I’d write it as plain text

```
Meeting at 5:00
```

Or if you need it in math mode with `\text`

```
$\text{5:00} + \text{1:00} = \text{6:00}$
```

But I can’t see a reason for that since times arn’t math and the colon can be misread as divide: `5:30 = 5/30 = \frac{5}{30}`.

**Advanced**
You could even define a command to have a globe appearance that can be change later easily:

```
\newcommand\Time[2]{%
   \text{#1:#2}% <------------------ change format here
}
```

and then use it like `\Time{5}{00}` in text or math mode.

To parse an input like `\Time{5:00}` you’ll need something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@time@parse#1:#2\end@time{%
   \text{#1\,h #2\,min}% <------------------ change format here
}
\newcommand{\Time}[1]{%
   \@time@parse#1\end@time
}
\makeatother
```

Where `\@time@parse` does the work and is called from within `\Time`

---

**full MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\TimeI}[2]{%
   \text{#1:#2}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\@time@parse#1:#2\end@time{%
   \text{#1\,h #2\,min}%
}
\newcommand{\TimeII}[1]{%
   \@time@parse#1\end@time
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Meeting at \TimeI{5}{00}

Meeting at \TimeII{5:00}
\end{document}
```